# Get 1d array from 2d array columnwise using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to do 1d array from 2d array using numpy with columns, but with ravel I could get only following:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(12)

In [3]: a = a.reshape(3,4)

In [4]: a
Out[4]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [5]: a.ravel()
Out[5]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

But I'd like to get:

```
array([ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found solution [np.flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel), just need to use flag 'F'

```
In [15]: a.ravel('F')
Out[15]: array([ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11])
```

Comment: asked 44 seconds ago, answered 44 seconds ago... how did you do it?

Comment: You could attach answer immediately with the question. While I typed the question I looked to the documentation and found solution. I posted it because may be it'll be useful for somebody.